# Python's orjson rised JSONDecodeError: str is not valid UTF-8

Tags: python, orjson

I trid to load json file with standart json library. It's works good but slowly:

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as jfile:
    lines = json.loads(jfile.read())
```

I try orjson librery, but the same code rise JSONDecodeError: str is not valid UTF-8

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as jfile:
    lines = orjson.loads(jfile.read())
```

How to handle this error?

Comment: Read the file in binary and give the bytes to orjson directly.

Comment: Thank you! It's work:    with open(file, 'rb') as jfile:
        lines = orjson.loads(jfile.read().decode("utf-8"))